# Kohana. Обработка результатов при ORM выборке из базы

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Я делаю простой запрос с Базе, допустим  
`ORM::factory('users')->find_all()`

На выходе получаю объект класса `Database_Result` (о структуре которого мало что можно найти). Далее мне необходимо перевести нужные мне данные из этой выборки к нужному мне виду (например даты перевести из `UnixTimeStamp`).

Вопрос в том, как удобнее, быстрее и правильнее это делать? В моделе я получаю объект и начинаю его циклом перелопачивать? и как его дальше в какой формат переводить? Вот раньше я получая массив, пробегался по нему от начала до конца и редактировал нужные мне данные,  тут же записывая в этот же массив с другим ключем, типа

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$res['readable_date'] = date("d.m.Y", $res['callunixdate']);
$res['readable_time'] = date("H:i:s", $res['callunixdate']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если такое написание `ORM::factory('users')->find_all()` верно, то думаю как-то так (по вашей схеме):

```
$users = ORM::factory('users')->find_all();

$arr = array();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $arr[]['id'] = $user->id;
    $arr[]['date'] = date("d.m.Y", $user->date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам "лопатить" один объект или массив, потом получать второй и снова его "лопатить" при выводе???

Не проще сразу с объектом работать? Примерно вот так:
Если у вас есть таблица в бд, в которой, скажем, есть 2 поля: table_id и value, то вы всегда можете их получить с помощью "магии" вот так:

```
$objects = ORM::factory('model')->find_all();
foreach($objects as $object)
{
    echo $object->value;
}
```

Comment: Да, а для работы с датами есть в Кохане отдельный класс DATE. Очень удобный.

Comment: т.е. передавать в вид необработанные данные, а там уже приводить к нормальному виду лучше?

Comment: это не противоречит логике MVC